# Задача на перебор списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Нужно написать программу, которая запрашивает число, проверяет есть ли оно в списке заданного заранее. 
Если да выводит один текст, если нет - другой.

Запрещено использовать оператор `in`. Нужно использовать цикл `for` и конструкцию `if`.

Вот мое решение, но оно не работает, где использовать `for` не понимаю.

```
list1 = [1, 5, 3, 2, 6, 8, 9]
a = int(input('Введите число:'))

if a == list1:
    print('Число есть в списке')
else:
    print('Числа нет в списке')
```

Comment: Имелось ввиду, нельзя использовать in для проверки вхождения числа в список.
В организации цикла for естественно можно.

Comment: А in нельззя использовать даже в цикле?

Comment: for использовать для прохождения по элементам заранее заданного списка и сравнения их с введенным числом.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
list1 = [1, 5, 3, 2, 6, 8, 9]
a = int(input('Введите число: '))
flag = False

for item in list1:
    if a == item:
        print(f'Число {a} есть в списке: {list1}')
        flag = True
        break
        
if not flag:       
    print(f'Числа {a} нет в списке: {list1}')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Редкий случай когда полезен [`for`/`else`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops):

```
list1 = [1, 5, 3, 2, 6, 8, 9]
a = int(input('Введите число:'))

for b in list1:
    if a == b:
        print('Число есть в списке')
        break
else:
    print('Числа нет в списке')
```

Answer (score 1):

Решение вообще без `in` (правда, и без цикла `for`, но рабочее решение от S. Nick уже есть, так что это просто забавный трюк):

```
list1 = [1, 5, 3, 2, 6, 8, 9]
number = int(input('Введите число: '))

set1 = set([number])
set2 = set(list1)

x = set1 & set2

if x != set():
    print('Есть!')
else:
    print('Нет!')
```

Смысл в том, что мы число и список преобразуем в множества и проверяем их пересечение.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать использовать `any`:

```
if any(a == el for el in list1):
    ...
else:
    ...
```

либо `list.count`:

```
if list1.count(a):
    ...
else:
    ...
```